# How to access variables of a referenced class library in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, class-library

I have a Windows Forms application with a reference for the class library in my Win-forms project.

1. The win-form has a combo-box and a button.
2. the class library has a global variable value1,value2 and other code which depending on value1 executes some code.

In win-form  i make a selection in the combo-box and on button click depending on the selection made i should assign a value to the variable "value1" of class library as value = true . 
i created an instance of the class library as 
    classlibraryname clb = new classlibrary() but after that i am not able to assign true to the class library variable "value1" .

how can i assign a value to variable value1???

I am new to working with c# and class libraries .please help

Comment: What do you mean by `not able to assign true`?  Do you get a compiler error, error at runtime? What EXACTLY happens?

Comment: The variables must declared `public` to access.  This is quite basic.  I recommend reading through programming basics and finding simple examples.

Comment: i am not knowing how to assign a value to the class library variable "value1" in winform application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable in the class library as public

```
    public bool variable1;
```

Then in your winform do the following:

```
    classlibraryname clb = new classlibraryname();
    clb.variable1 = true;
```